# How to make a server redirect a client to another server?

Tags: java, sockets, authentication, server

So I am working on socket programming project, where the client connects first to an authentication server and once the login is successful the client is then connected to the game server.

I created a basic code and hardcoded the username/password for now, but will be using a database later.

the problem I am facing is that I do not know how to transfer the client from authentication server to game server once login is successful

here is my loginServer thead that handle the login part.

```
public class LoginServerThread extends Thread {
private Socket socket;

public LoginServerThread(Socket socket){
    this.socket = socket;
}
@Override
public void run(){
    try{
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("Client Connected");

        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
        String echoString;

        boolean unlock = false;

        while (!unlock){
            output.println("USERNAME: ");
            echoString = input.readLine();
            if(echoString.equals("exit")){
                break;
            } else if (echoString.equals("username")){

                for(int i = 0; i < 3;){
                    output.println("PASSWORD: ");
                    echoString = input.readLine();{

                        if(echoString.equals("password")){
                            output.println("Login Successful");
                            unlock = true;
                            break;

                        }else{
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            socket.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: It seems like your real question is something like "how to make a server redirect a client to another server", which most likely involves giving the client a *token* of some sort, and information about where to find the next server.

Comment: your authentication and game server deploy in one jvm or in different jvm?

Comment: @TongChen same jvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume authentication and game server deploy in one jvm.When login success don't close the socket,but tranfer the socket to `GameServerThread`:
LoginServer just check authentication:

```
public class LoginServer {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginServer.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket loginServer = new ServerSocket();
        SocketAddress serverSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 5230);
        loginServer.bind(serverSocketAddress);
        for (; ; ) {
            Socket socket = loginServer.accept();
            if (loginCHeck(socket)) {
                // transfer to game server thread to process
                log.info("socket check begin create thread to process");
                new GameServerThread(socket).run();
            } else {
                // authentication failed process
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean loginCHeck(Socket socket) {
        // check authentication 
        return true;
    }
}
```

public class GameServerThread extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;

```
public GameServerThread(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // do your really want to do
}
```

}

This method has the following shortcoming:
One socket need one thread to process,when have two many client the server's thread may run out. In order to overcome this,you can use `Java NIO API` to do the same work.

Comment: thank you but how to do to transfer it over? your code just show how to create the game thread but now how to hand the client over to the game server.

Comment: @Adam you can in you loginServerThread call `new GameServerThread(socket)` to create a thread and start it. in GameServerThread can read data from client then if the data represent close, the thread can close socket.later,i write a complete example.

Comment: this is very good, so if I understood it right when calling new GameServerThread(socket).run(); it pass the socket to GameServerThread to run. how about login server, does it close itself automatically or I should do something like loginserver.close(); ?  another questions,  what's this line for private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginServer.class);

Comment: your login server is you endpoint,every client want to connection to server must connect to login server,it will always work and accept client connection until you want to close server.  `private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginServer.class)` it is auto generated by my IDEA，it's just used for log.

Comment: one last question, what's the role of   private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginServer.class); and what does loginServer.bind(serverSocketAddress); do ?

Comment: First,the filed log is used for log info to file,this is very importan in production,if you interested you can refer this [document](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/).

Comment: Second, `loginServer.bind(serverSocketAddress)` every tcp connection contains five element: source address(IP)、source porta、destination address、destination port and transfer Protocol. The server socket only bind to some address,then you client can connect to,it like if you want send email to some body,first you must konw the emall address